# Android R.anim,shake not found

Tags: android, animation, button

I have followed the tutorial at:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Animation1.html

The code is fine until I get to:

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
```

It would appear that R.anim does not exist, eclipse suggests creating a field in in type R or creating a constant in type R. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't believe either are the solution.

I am running Google APIs, platform 2.2, API 8 - I have tried higher levels but it didn't make a difference. All that I am trying to accomplish is a button shake on click...

Any feedback is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Thats what the tutorial calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the shake animation xml file. It will reside in

> /res/anim/shake.xml

and it would look like this:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="10" android:duration="1000"
 android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7" />
```

You then also need the interpolator (cycle_7.xml):

```
 <cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:cycles="7" />
```

These files can both be found in

> /path/to/android_sdk/samples/android-15/ApiDemos/res/anim